# Linkedin API access token fetch exception

Tags: linkedin-api

When I want to obtain access token, it throws WebException. The following code gets access token before June 21st. After this time, it throws WebException

```
    var linkAccessToken = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + code + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri + "&client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret;
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(linkAccessToken);

    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

    try
    {
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        // ex.Status is WebExceptionStatus.SendFailure
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code before create a request!

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```